# Javafx 2 Notification Refresh

Tags: javafx-2, partial-page-refresh

I have a requirement in JavaFX 2 to display the notifications on the header. These notifications are populated in the database through an external system.

When a new notification is inserted in the database, my JavaFX application should listen to the same and refresh the header.

One solution I can think about is to implement a timeline that triggers the code to retrieve the latest notification status once every fixed time period, may be once every 2 mins.

Other than this, is there any other way to achieve this? Any hints on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new `Task` that would be listening (or checking) for changes in your database.  This `Task` would be running in a different `Thread` as not to block your UI.  Once a change occurs, it can then update your UI.

Your code could look like this :

```
//... initialize your variables.
task = new DatabaseWatcher();
executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.execute(task);
```

And your `DatabaseWatcher` :

```
public class DatabaseWatcher extends Task<Object> {
    public DatabaseWatcher() {
        //initialize here
    }

    @Override
    protected Object call() throws Exception {
        //Get data from database
        //if new update :
        updateUI();
        return null;
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Set your new values in your UI
                //Call the method in your UI to update values.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This should get you started on the right path.

#### See Also

- [Multiple FXML with Controllers, share object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166786/multiple-fxml-with-controllers-share-object/12167932#12167932), more specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12167932/686036)
- [javafx, update ui from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690683/javafx-update-ui-from-another-thread)
- [Concurrency in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm)