# JavaFX & GUI-Threads: Change button text from Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

I have a GUI with a TextArea and a Save Button. When I press the latter the text is saved. This takes around 2 seconds. During the process of saving the buttons should get another caption than before and after saving.

Here is my code:

```
    saveButton.setText("Saving...");
    Util.print("Saving...");

    Thread saveIt = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Util.print(ex);
                }
                saveButton.setText("Saved!");
                Util.print("Saved!");
            });
        }
    });
    saveIt.setDaemon(true);
    saveIt.start();
```

**What happens:**

The following output is produced on the command line after pressing the button:

```
Saving...
Saved!
```

The command line prints "Saving..." directly after I click on saveButton. 2 seconds after pressing saveButton the command line prints "Saved!" and the button caption changes to "Saved!".

**What I would expect:**

The command line output ***and the button caption*** show "Saving..." directly after I click on the save button. After 2 seconds the caption changes to "Saved!".

**How can I achieve the expected behaviour?**

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

P.S.: I know so many people have had problems with changing GUI elements from Threads. I already read some articles on StackOverflow & the web about it, but this one's a too hard nut for me. Just for reference, here is some of the things I tried so far, among others Tasks:

[Constantly Update UI in Java FX worker thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497845/constantly-update-ui-in-java-fx-worker-thread)

[Why am I getting java.lang.IllegalStateException "Not on FX application thread" on JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850191/why-am-i-getting-java-lang-illegalstateexception-on-javafx)

[javafx, update ui from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690683/javafx-update-ui-from-another-thread)

http://blog.axxg.de/javafx-ui-thread-update/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to put the Thread.sleep() part out of the Platform.runLater() process. Seemingly runLater() must as few workload as possible.

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    saveButton.setText("Saving...");
    Util.print("Saving...");
});


Thread saveIt = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Util.print(ex);
        }
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            saveButton.setText("Saved!");
            Util.print("Saved!");
        });
    }
});
saveIt.setDaemon(true);
saveIt.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

try wrapping your **first** setText into a Platform.runLater like this:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
   saveButton.setText("Saving...");
});
```

Every change made to a JavaFX UI component has to been called from the JavaFX thread using the Platform.runLater

Comment: It works in about 1 out of 10 cases. I've tried wrapping in a seperate Thread like in example code, doesn't work either. Also not if I utilize Thread.join().